# Reading a value from Textfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to read a value from textfied in Java but I am not able to read it
Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TextField extends JDialog {
  TextField() {
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("SAMPLE PROGRAM");
    frm.setBounds(150,150,420,400);
    frm.setLayout(null);
    Container content = frm.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    text.setBounds(70,25,100,30);
    JButton button1, button2; 
    button1 = new JButton("PROGRAMMER");
    button2 = new JButton("USER");
    button1.setBounds(270,25,120,50);
    button2.setBounds(270,90,120,50);
    button1.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    button2.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    frm.add(button1);
    frm.add(button2);
    frm.add(text);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.setResizable(false);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TextField();
  }
  class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
      String str = new String();     
      str = e.getActionCommand();    
      System.out.println(" " + str);
    }
  }  
}
```

I tried the following methods

1.In the Class Textfield i used this method under button2.addactionlistener.It gave an error

Cannot refer to a non-final variable text inside an inner class defined in a different method

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {  
    if(text.getText().equals("joe"))
```

2.In the class ButtonHandler

it says that text cannot be resolved

**What Method should i use to read the textfield and in which class should in read it**

Comment: could you make your classes a little clearer and type in all the necessary code? The first class has no method.

Comment: Why all the '>' characters preceding the code lines?  Please make more effort in future, that lot reads like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: no way around reading a basic java tutorial/textbook and learning its content :-) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) if you rename (possible conflict with with AWT API with name TextField) and remove JDialog, because it is never used

```
public class TextField extends JDialog { TextField(){
```

to

```
public class MyTextField { public MyTextField(){
```

2) and change the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TextField();
}
```

to

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            private final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyTextField textField = new MyTextField();
            }
        });
    }
```

3) remove all chars `>`

4) add DefaultCloseOparation for JFrame, otherwise your program will stay in the memory until your PC is restarted or switched off

5) remove all un_[Swing methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) and use a [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: I made an edit.  Roll it back if I guessed wrong as to what you meant.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

String str = text.getText();

this should work if you replace

```
str = e.getActionCommand();
```

with

```
 String str = text.getText();
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to create the JTextField as a static JTextField or add the final modifier.

PS: next time, only put in the necessary code, not the JFrame or JButtons, it just makes reading the code easier.

Comment: Say what, make it a static field ? I hope that's not a serious suggestion. It will solve the compile problem, but that's about all it will solve. In return, you get a bunch of problems and bad design

Comment: It's true that it ends up with bad software design, but judging by the code, I'd say that the level of the coder isn't at the point of making grand scale programs and so, using static will make it easier. Not only that, when I program (please tell me if this is bad) I tend to not use inheritance and instead, make important variables static, and make many methods in the place of classes.

Comment: And what if you make two instances of that class ... are they going to share the same static field ? static instances belong to the class, and not to an instance of the class. So a JTextField, part of your UI, should never be a static instance

Comment: I read through the code again after  a year, and I released how dumb my answer was.